# windows missing from boot menu, manjaro

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

Suddenly windows is missing from bootmenu maybe after an update, or maybe after a sudden shutdown during windows boot process.

`os-prober` output:

```
/dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
/dev/sdb3:Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (18.04):Ubuntu:linux
```

`efibootmgr -v` output:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0008,0000,0007,0009
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,93828d50-bca4-01d4-a842-c149525eea00,0x800,0x145000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...3................
Boot0001* manjaro   HD(1,GPT,65c82838-e33c-4e92-9be0-c427de042756,0x800,0x145000)/File(\EFI\manjaro\grubx64.efi)
Boot0007* UEFI: WDC WD10SPZX-75Z10T1, Partition 1   HD(1,GPT,93828d50-bca4-01d4-a842-c149525eea00,0x800,0x145000)/File(EFI\boot\bootx64.efi)..BO
Boot0008* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,93828d50-bca4-01d4-a842-c149525eea00,0x800,0x145000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0009* UEFI: Micron 1100 SATA 256GB, Partition 1 HD(1,GPT,65c82838-e33c-4e92-9be0-c427de042756,0x800,0x145000)/File(EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)..BO
```

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   650M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   651G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0 279.9G  0 part /run/media/user/lincom
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   650M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0  70.2G  0 part /run/media/user/6A5E35815E35475B
├─sdb3   8:19   0  27.9G  0 part /run/media/user/43f98f19-cd98-403a-96bd-6bac85
├─sdb4   8:20   0    51G  0 part /
├─sdb5   8:21   0  33.3G  0 part /run/media/user/vms
└─sdb6   8:22   0  55.5G  0 part /home
```

I used the following command to reinstall grub:

```bsh
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=manjaro --recheck
sudo update-grub
```

But it still did not find the Windows (or the Ubuntu).

All the operating systems were installed in UEFI mode and using the same efi partition for boot.

```
~/# uname -r
5.4.101-1-MANJARO
~/$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04~19~manjaro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Actual Answer

Expanding on [@Jahid response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638740/windows-missing-from-boot-menu-manjaro?newreg=cd0ab8ccb0c0479680eac1b78ea50133#answer-638784) if you have updated grub recently and either your boot menu or entires of it have disappeared you will need to edit `/etc/default/grub` and add/edit one or more of the following lines:

If your boot menu is not showing

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

If other operating systems are missing (applies to Linux or Windows, same disk or another disk, HDD, SSD or NVMe).

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

Now **VERY IMPORTANT** make sure that after editing this file you run `sudo update-grub` for the changes to apply. Editing `/etc/default/grub` on it's own does nothing.

## Additional Info

Some other commands you might find useful are listed in the question, `lsblk` will list disks and partitions, `fdisk -l` will give you more info (like which disk Windows is on), `sudo os-prober` will list all the additional operating systems that can be found (Linux and Windows but not the one you're currently running).

Files and folders that may be of interest if none of the above helps are as follows:

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
/etc/grub.d/
/etc/default/grub
```

Grub Documentation (for reference), the "Writing your own configuration file" section lists options you can add in your `/etc/default/grub` file.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-documentation.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the new version of `grub` does not probe for other operating systems by default anymore. You need to add:

```bsh
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

in `/etc/default/grub`

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, you need to update-grub to apply this change.